# Ant task external program hangs

Tags: ant, windows-server-2003

I am running the mqsicreatbar.exe program from ANT and it hangs after sometime.
can someone please provide any help. The same command works fine in command line

```
Ant Version: 1.8.2    OS version: Windows Server 2003
```

here is the code I have issue

```
protected String runS(Commandline cmdline, String outputProperty) {
        //String   outV  = "opts.mb.runS.output" + i++;

        Project  aProj = getProject();

        ExecTask exe   = (ExecTask) aProj.createTask("exec");
        Commandline.Argument arg = exe.createArg();
        exe.setExecutable(cmdline.getExecutable());
        arg.setLine(Commandline.toString(cmdline.getArguments()));
        exe.setOutputproperty(outputProperty);
        exe.execute();
        System.out.println( "runS: " + outputProperty  + " : " );

        return aProj.getProperty(outputProperty);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the command you are trying to run (batch file, etc) you make need to specify that the "executable" for the exec task is "cmd.exe" and specify your actually executable as command line arguments.

http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#batch-shell-execute

Comment: NOTE: the linked example uses `os="Windows NT"` which will only execute if the OS name is "Windows NT". This doesn't execute on "Windows Server 2008 R2" for example. See [Exec Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) documentation for details.